# How do I run similar commands with files in ten separate folders?

Tags: text-processing, batch

I have a folder `y2015` in which I have ten subdirectories (`d001`, `d002`, `d003`, ..., `d010`).

In each `dXXX` folder I have to run these commands which are shown below:

```bash
gd2e.py -mkTreeS myKinTree
rm /myKinTree/ppp_0.tree
cp /home/user/GipsyX-1.1/share/gd2e/DefaultTreeSeries/myKinTree/ppp_0.tree  /myKinTree/
rinex2staDb.py y2015/d001/hyde0010.15d.Z
rnxEditGde.py -data y2015/d001/hyde0010.15d.Z -rate 30
gd2e.py -drEditedFile data.dr.gz -recList HYDE -staDb fromRnx.sta_db -HighRate -trees myKinTree/
```

I need to go back to `d002` after executing the above commands in `d001`.

Be careful, because in `d002` I want to replace `rinex2staDb.py y2015/d001/hyde0010.15d.Z` with `rinex2staDb.py y2015/d002/hyde0020.15d.Z` and so on for the other folders `d003`, `d004`, ..., `d010`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shell loop for this. I'll show the code first but please read the caveats below before you use it.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for i in {001..010}; do
    gd2e.py -mkTreeS myKinTree
    rm /myKinTree/ppp_0.tree
    cp /home/user/GipsyX-1.1/share/gd2e/DefaultTreeSeries/myKinTree/ppp_0.tree  /myKinTree/
    rinex2staDb.py "y2015/d${i}/hyde${i}0.15d.Z"
    rnxEditGde.py -data "y2015/d${i}/hyde${i}0.15d.Z" -rate 30
    gd2e.py -drEditedFile data.dr.gz -recList HYDE -staDb fromRnx.sta_db -HighRate -trees myKinTree/
done
```

You may well need to modify this script. You should look it over to ensure that each place you want values from `001` to `010` plugged in, there is an `${i}`, and that there are no `${i}`s anywhere else. **I also recommend backing up all files that would be affected by running it.**

You mentioned that you need to run commands "In each dXXX folder" but you're using paths that themselves have prefixes like `y2015/d001/`. So I have assumed that you actually do *not* want to `cd` into each directory--doing so would keep those paths from working.

You can save that in a file *`script`*. (You'll probably want to call it something meaningful, but I don't know a good name because I don't know the wider context in which you're running these commands.) Then make the script executable with `chmod +x script` and run it with `./script`.

This uses [a `for` loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs) (with [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion)) and [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). I've written `${i}` rather than `$i` because in some places in the script, such as `hyde${i}0.15d.Z`, writing `$i` instead would attempt to expand a different (presumably unset) variable `$i0`. The braces in `${i}`, which is a simple usage of parameter expansion, don't mean the same thing as the braces in `{001..010}`, which is a range for brace expansion.

Comment: Hello, The above program is working till 4th line, That is copying the file command cp... THen in line 5: rinex2staDb.py "y2015/d${i}/hyde${i}0.15d.Z" . It is showing command not found.. where as if i execute the same command as rinex2staDb.py y2015/d001/hyde0010.15d.Z it is executing

Comment: @MohammedYousuf Does it show any output at all *other* than `command not found`? Also, where is the file `rinex2staDb.py` file located, and how is it found? Is it in a directory in your `$PATH`?

Comment: rinex2staDb.py is not in same directory. If this command does not executed, then next commands also fails. shall i copy this program rinex2staDb.py from my path to this folder everytime in every folder...

Comment: @MohammedYousuf No, you should probably not copy it, and doing so would probably not help. Instead, can you explain *why* you expect it to run? When it is found, how is it found? Is it in a directory in your `$PATH`? What is the output of `type -a rinex2staDb.py`? Also, are you sure the `command not found` message is for `rinex2staDb.py` itself? Could it be for something that `rinex2staDb.py` runs? Does the message consist of the exact sequence of characters `command not found` *with nothing else* or does it contain other characters? (For example, is it `rinex2staDb.py: command not found`?)

Comment: I have made few changes as follows    for i in {001..003}; do
cd d${i}
    gd2e.py -mkTreeS myKinTree
    rm myKinTree/ppp_0.tree
    cp /home/user/GipsyX-1.1/share/gd2e/DefaultTreeSeries/myKinTree/ppp_0.tree  myKinTree/
    rinex2staDb.py hyde$i0.15d.Z
    rnxEditGde.py -data hyde$i0.15d.Z -rate 30
    gd2e.py -drEditedFile data.dr.gz -recList HYDE -staDb fromRnx.sta_db -HighRate -trees myKinTree/
cd ..
done

Comment: yes it is rinex2staDb.py command not found

Comment: in same terminal if i execute rinex2staDb.py hyde0010.15d.Z

Comment: it is executing and giveing output a file fromRnx.sta_db which is common if i execute for each day data separately without bash also gives the same thing..

Comment: You please tell me if we have any replacement to ${i} in hyde${i}0.15d.Z. after every loop this should be changed

Comment: @MohammedYousuf Regarding the comment where you said "I have made few changes...", I don't know really what changes you've made, because comments collapse whitespace. Also, don't know if you're saying you made changes and they *worked*, that you made changes and they *still did not* work, or that the version with the changes is the only one you've used (and does not work). Please edit you original question to add the code you've shown here as well as the output of `type -a rinex2staDb.py` and `echo "$PATH"`, and to describe, in detail, everything you've attempted to describe here.

Comment: echo "$PATH" gives /home/user/GipsyX-1.1/lib/openmpi/bin:/home/user/GipsyX-1.1/bin:/home/user/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin type -a rinex2staDb.py showing rinex2staDb.py not found

Comment: @MohammedYousuf Thanks, but please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1166383/edit) and include, to the best of your ability, all the information [I requested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166383/how-do-i-run-similar-commands-with-files-in-ten-separate-folders/1166391?noredirect=1#comment1945947_1166391). Most of your comments here are hard for me to understand. The most important ones, which show code and the output of commands, may be impossible for *anyone* to understand, because that doesn't appear correctly in comments. And if you edit, other people may notice and help.